# What is the difference between Avatar(Incarnation) and Punarjanma(Rebirth)?

Tags: avatars, rebirth

What is the difference between Avatar(Incarnation) and Punarjanma(Rebirth)?

Does the first only apply for Swarg Lok and the second apply only for Mrutyu Lok? I mean Avatar happens only with Gods/Goddess Punarjanma happens only with living beings in the world?

Does atma not have a role in case of Avatar(Incarnation)?

Answer (score 1):

Gita makes the distinction clear:

> 2.27 For death of anyone born is certain, and of the dead (re-) birth is a certainly. Therefore you ought not to grieve over an inevitable fact.(Rebirth)
>
> 4.7 O scion of the Bharata dynasty, whenever there is a decline one virtue and increase of vice, then do I manifest Myself. (Incarnation)

Jivatma is reborn, Paramatma takes Avataara form. For Avaataaras, the deha and dehi is not different like that of jivas. The Avaataara hides Hisnreal nature by His Maya.

Comment: Do you mean to say Jivatma presents with in reborn like us and Paramatma presents with in Avatar's like Lord Krishna, Lord Rama etc?

Comment: Can you please get me more description to understand the difference